# ASP.NET Core 6 how to access IWebHostEnvironment before builder.Build() in Program.cs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I want to use `Environment.IsDevelopment()` before `builder.Build()` in `Program.cs`. How should I do that?

```
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
 //Code: reach environment
 var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: Please include code as text rather than an image of it.

Comment: I think you can set a variable in appsetting.json and read the configuration before `builder.Build()`

Comment: It works fine if you use code: `var env= builder.Environment.IsDevelopment();` before `builder.Biuld()`.

Comment: @phuzi it's Done.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can access which environment you are currently running as by using:

```
builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()
```

Prior to the application being built at this point:

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

After this code has run you would use:

```
app.Environment.IsDevelopment()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for ContentRootPath in a Web Application like me you can do:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();

var path = ((IWebHostEnvironment)builder.Environment).ContentRootPath;
```

Answer (score -2):

It may not be what you are looking for, but I have used:

```
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

after

```
var app = builder.Build();
```

and before

```
app.Run();
```

This allows for more verbose exception pages in production (had a few issues where errors were thrown in production but not in development).